# graphql-compose: require argument that's an input type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-compose

Below is an example of a resolver I'm writing that's using [graphql-compose](https://graphql-compose.github.io/docs/basics/what-is-resolver.html) to help build up our schema.

```
const createResolver = schemaComposer.createResolver({
  kind: 'mutation',
  name: 'SomeNameHere',
  type: SomeTypeNameTC,
  args: {
    inputForm: InputFormITC,
  },
  resolve: ({ args }) => {
    return createInputForm(args.inputForm);
  }
});
```

My question is regarding the `args` section of the resolver. How can I require that the `inputForm` argument is required in the schema? If I were to declare an ID to also be passed in, as an example, I could require the ID in the schema by adding an exclamation mark.

If, however, I add an (!) to the ITC object I believe that just tells JS to require that argument and not the GraphQL schema.

```
args: {
  id: 'ID!'
  inputForm: InputFormITC!
}
```

I worked around this by doing something like `inputForm: 'InputFormInput!'` but I'd rather have the actual object to make it easier to jump around in our IDE. Is such a thing possible in graphql-compose?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett I did, yes. Just posted an answer to the post.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [graphql-compose InputTypeComposer](https://graphql-compose.github.io/docs/api/InputTypeComposer.html#nonnull) shows a "NonNull" getter for input types. To require an input type argument to be required the syntax would look like so:

```
args: {
  inputForm: InputFormITC.NonNull
}
```

When viewing the schema, the input type will now show an exclamation mark (!) indicating that it's a required argument.